# How to perform dynamic where queries with firestore and add indexes

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

In my site i am conducting a survey like `tests`, each test has `attendies` sub collection look like this

[image]

When someone finishes a test i also add their `uid` to `completed` field like i drawn in the box. Now i want to query `tests` based on `status == completed`.

Here is what i tried

```
    this.completedModulesRef$ = this.afs.collection('tests', ref => 
           ref.orderBy('moduleNum', 'desc')
              .where('completed.'+auth.uid+'.status','==','completed'));

    this.completedModules$ = this.completedModulesRef$.valueChanges();
```

Then firestore asked me to add indexes, when i follow the generated link to add indexes i got this

[image]
which is pointing to `completed.CurrentUserId.status`. I believe this only work for current user.

I have few question

1) `.where('completed.'+auth.uid+'.status','==','completed')` Is this a valid query?

2) If yes how can i index it?

3) Any way to query the top collections based on sub collection value?. (this is what i really want)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I can only answer for number 3, which I know is not possible atm. I'm curious about the other two as well.

Comment: @DarkNeuron That was a bad database modal by me. I moved entire completed object  to  `users/uid/tests/tesId` as a collection, so when a user completes a test it will be find under his directory.

Comment: Maybe you can achieve this using GraphQL queries?

Answer (score 0):

You could just instead use an array of objects (each object represents one attendie) to track all the completed attendies. Arrays are indexed in firestore.

The data structure of the array would be:

```
compeleted: [{}] = [
  {id: string, points: number, status: string}
]
```

This might not be the most optimal database model depending on how and where you want to fetch the data but it will be indexed and you will be able to query it. I would consider storing the points and status in the subcollection of attendies. Have a look at grouped collection queries in firestore - new feature where you can query across all attendies subcollections at once - for any attendie with a certain id and a status of complete if you want to fetch all the tests that one attendie completed.